# Hide Rows based on Cell Data

Tags: excel, vba

I want to hide some of the Rows in a worksheet if the Cell in column A contains 0. This is calculated using a formula.

E.g. If A1 contains value "0", row#1 should get hidden.

I know I can write this code on Sheet's Activate Event but it is slowing down the file's performance.

Is there a good way to achieve the same without compromising file's performance?

Answer (score 2):

you could always use `filter` to achieve this. I think that would be much more efficient.

**Edit:**
To improve performance of your code, you could do the following:

1. Turn off the Events
2. Turn off the Calculations

Before running the loop to hide rows

```
With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .Cursor = xlWait
End With
```

After the loop is over

```
With Excel.Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    .Cursor = xlDefault
End With
```

Hope this helps. Also explicitly using variables could give a boost to performance
 and Calculation. Although explicitly declaring your variables should help too.

Comment: Yes that is but I don't want the user to see that the data is filtered and neither want to allow them to change the data filter. Is it possible using code?

Comment: Not an answer - should have been posted as a comment

Comment: @brettdj: I beg to differ. The underlying question was "Is there a good way to achieve the same without compromising file's performance?". And using "filter" is one way to do the same. Please let me know in detail why you disagree.

Comment: In Detail? Beacuse a one line use `Filter` isn't an answer.

Comment: @Konstant: Thanks. I didn't make the calculation manual. Will try that as well. I'm sure that will speed it up!